# How are undefined, false, and null working here?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have tried the following JavaScript code:

```
> var {a} = undefined;
Thrown:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `a` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
> var {a} = false;
undefined
```

Essentially, can someone explain this error to me? Why does it occur, and how does {a} get set as `undefined` in the second line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you try to access field `a` of undefined, which leads to error. You can try to access `undefined` fields manually:

```
console.log(undefined.a);
```

It will lead to:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
```

In the second example you access `a` field of false, but false doesn't have `a` field, that's why it is `undefined`. You can test it manually to:

```
console.log(false.a);
// undefined
```

If you want to avoid `undefined` values ​​after destructuring you can assign a default value:

```
let { a = "default value" } = false;
console.log(a);
// default value
```